# How can I override an C++ standard-library class function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, iostream

How can I override a C++ standard-library class function? In my application, I use `ofstream` objects in many different places of code. And now I want to open files in a different permission mode in Linux, Ubuntu. But `open` function of `ofstream` has no parameter to specify the permission mode of the file it creats.

Now I want to override `open()` function of `ofstream` class so it will get a parameter to specify the permissions for user access.

Answer (score 5):

For starters, to clarify your terminology, the STL usually refers to the subset of the C++ standard library containing the containers, iterators, and algorithms.  The streams classes are part of the C++ standard library, but are usually not bundled together with the STL.  Some purists will insist that there is no such thing as the STL in the C++ standard library (since the STL is, technically speaking, a third-party library that was adopted into the standard), but most C++ programmers will know what you mean.

As for your question, there is no way within the standard to specify permission modes with `ofstream`.  If you want to create your own custom stream class that is like `ofstream` but which supports permissions, your best bet would be to do the following:

1. Create a subclass of `basic_streambuf` that allows you to open, write, and possibly read files while specifying Unix permissions.  The streams classes are designed so that the details of communicating with physical devices like disk, networks, and the console are all handled by the `basic_streambuf` class and its derived classes.  If you want to make your own stream class, implementing a stream buffer would be an excellent first step.
2. Define your own class that subclasses `basic_ostream` and installs your custom `basic_streambuf`.  By default, the `basic_ostream` supports all of the standard output routines by implementing them in terms of the underlying `basic_streambuf` object.  Once you have your own stream buffer, building a `basic_ostream` class that uses that `streambuf` will cause all of the standard stream operations on that class (such as `<<`) to start making the appropriate calls to your `streambuf`.

If you'd like more details on this, an excellent reference is [Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201183951).  As a shameless plug, I have used the techniques from this book to build [a stream class that wraps a socket connection](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=nstream).  While a lot of the code in my stream won't be particularly useful, the basic structure should help you get started.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is not answering your question directly as I wouldn't advise overriding `ofstream::open`.

Instead couldn't you use the first suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683051/file-and-istream-connect-the-two) post? Open the file as you normally would to get the correct permissions, and then construct an `ofstream` from the file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class gstream: public std::ofstream
{

void open(const std::string& filename, ios_base::openmode mode,int stuff)
        {
                //put stuff here

        }
};

int main() {

        gstream test;
//io stuff
return 0;
}
```

seems to work here.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create a wrapper class that contains an 'ofstream' object and has the interface you want, and passes the work onto its 'oftstream' member.  It would look like this.